# iOS Notifications: callbacks not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

I'm implenting a reminder feature for an app through local notifications.
The user will setup times and repetition intervals and the app will schedule the respective notifications like this:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = ...;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

For this to work I need to register my notification types like this:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings;

notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings
                         settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                               categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
  registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

Although the notifications are be scheduled correctly none of the AppDelegate callbacks (`didRegisterUserNotificationSettings`, `didReceiveLocalNotification`) are called. But I need to react to
notifications when the app is in the foreground.

Registering notification settings should trigger a callback message in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
   NSLog(@"Callback called.");
}
```

It works just fine for a quick test project (New Project -> Single View App -> add register code and callback -> launch). The callback gets called.

However, in the real app it does not work.

I completly stripped my apps AppDelegate (removed custom init code, no ui loading) so that it just registers the notification settings. A fresh app install triggers the user confirmation dialog correctly. But the callbacks won't get called.

Am I missing a build setting/compiler flag? I'm not aware of any special settings for the app pointing in that direction. I can't spot any difference to the example project.

Xcode 7.2 , iPod5 iOS9.2.1

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: @LouFranco There is nothing. I even checked the complete device log.

Comment: @lupz did you tried another notification types ?  may be `UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound`

Comment: @sage444 yes I did. I found the reason for this issue. Thanks for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch. This is makes a perfect reason for a facepalm...

In order to detect certain ui events within the whole app, the AppDelegate was changed to exdend `UIApplication` so I could use the `- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` callback. The AppDelegate should normally extend `UIResponder`.

You can setup different classes for both uses in the `main.m`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    @try {
      // Original AppDelegate now extending UIResponder
      NSString *mainDelegate = NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]);
      // New class extending UIApplication
      NSString *mainClass    = NSStringFromClass([AppMain class]);

      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, mainClass, mainDelegate);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
      NSLog(@"%@", [exception reason]);
    }
  }
}
```

I thank everybody for their suggestions.
Sometimes you have to take a step back.